# Can't read SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm storing some values in my PreferencesFragment in this way:

```
// SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Test", 0);
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();

SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();

edit.putInt(getString(R.string.valOneKey), 100);
edit.putInt(getString(R.string.valTwoKey), 200);
edit.commit();
```

Then, I want to read the preferences in a non activity class:

```
// SharedPreferences prefs = ActivityHandler.getCurrentActivity().getSharedPreferences("Test", 0);
SharedPreferences prefs = ActivityHandler.getCurrentActivity().getPreferences(0);

int valOne = prefs.getInt(ActivityHandler.getCurrentActivity().getString(R.string.valOneKey), 0);
int valTwo = prefs.getInt(ActivityHandler.getCurrentActivity().getString(R.string.valTwoKey), 0);
```

I've tried also the uncommented code, but I get always 0 for both values.

Comment: Can the downvoters explain why? Would be helpful for me, because I don't understand that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

### Store with SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("my_pref", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);

Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("KEY", VAL);
..
..
editor.commit();
```

### Retrieve from SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
                "my_pref", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
int size = sharedPref.getInt("KEY", default_VAL);
```

This will be helpful...thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. Each time you are getting a different shared preference. Use this code:

**For storing value:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Test", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();

edit.putInt(getString(R.string.valOneKey), 100);
edit.putInt(getString(R.string.valTwoKey), 200);
edit.commit();
```

**For fetching value:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Test", 0);
int valOne = prefs.getInt(ActivityHandler.getCurrentActivity().getString(R.string.valOneKey), 0);
int valTwo = prefs.getInt(ActivityHandler.getCurrentActivity().getString(R.string.valTwoKey), 0);
```

Hope this will help you.